# Is there any way to set Gradient with different Colors in Shinobi Controls for iOS

Tags: ios, mobile

I have 4 SChartLineSeries (different line colors say Read, Green, Yellow, Blue). These all 4 may cross each others at any point. I have to fill it with Gradient also. My Points are :

1. If we have Yellow line at lowest place along with x-axis, we can manage the Gradient according to Yellow.

   series.style.showFill = YES;

   series.style.areaColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:65.0 / 255.0 green:165.0 / 255.0 blue:65.0 / 255.0 alpha:1];

   series.style.areaColorLowGradient = [UIColor colorWithRed:35.0 / 255.0 green:75.0 / 255.0 blue:35.0 / 255.0 alpha:1];
2. BUT, if Red line crosses Yellow line at any point ( Yellow line is no longer at bottom place) and become the most bottom line. Now I have to make gradient effect in such a manner that Yellow Line will be having Gradient with Yellow effect under it and Red line will be having Gradient with Red effect under it. and so on.
3. AND, same for the line just above the most bottom line. we have to make gradient effect for it. and if other line crosses this then color for gradient should be change. and if third line cut the second one, again color is to be changed. and so on. BUT gradient effect should NOT go to bottom, it should be stopped where it meets to next line.

I have to show these effect for all lines.

So, any idea please.

Thanks for response.

Comment: Can Any one please give me any idea regarding this ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'll need to stack your series and split your series into smaller series:

To stack your series, set the stackIndex property of each to the same NSNumber - for example:

```
lineSeries.stackIndex = @0;
```

This will mean that your line fills draw in bands, the 'lowest' up to the next lowest, and so on. You'll also need to provide the yValues for each datapoint as an offset from the previous (lower) series yValue for the same xValue.

This alone won't fix your issue with the lines overlapping though - to address this you can split your data into different sections (different series) at each point where the ordering of the series changes (whenever two lines cross). This approach means that your datasource will have to do a fair amount of work before you pass your data to the chart - and you may end up with lots of series - but it should produce the effect you're after. Hope this helps! =)

Disclaimer: I work on ShinobiCharts.